# What is a good method for detection of rare occurencies of speech in noisy audio data?

Tags: anomaly-detection, audio-recognition

I have some audio recordings (with relatively static but noisy background, e.g., wind in an open area) with small number of short occurrences of speech (~1% of the total audio duration).

What would be a good method to detect the speech occurences in an unsupervised manner?

I have tried simple thresholding on a spectrogram, but this is problematic since:

- The intensity of the background can wary with time (i.e. noise is louder sometimes)
- Different speech segments need not to be similar to each other
- Often, speech is too quiet (compared to the average loudness of the background) and is overlaid by noise

This may seem like quite a hard task, however I can easily notice the speech segments by listening to the audio/looking at the spectrogram, since spectrogram of speech has some distinct structure (although it is non-trivial to rely on the structure for detection as it is still quite non-regular).

- Note that I just want to detect intervals with something sounding like human speech (or, say, something distinct enough from the background, since data typically has no other sound sources besides background/speech).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Detecting speech specifically is a well known problem, generally called [Voice Activity Detection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voice_activity_detection) (VAD).
The simplest mechanisms just calculate a time-averaged ratio of energy in the speech frequencies compared to total energy, many implementations on Github of this idea. The audio codes for speech also tend to include a VAD component. A modern example can be found in [libvad](https://github.com/dpirch/libfvad), based on the VAD from WebRTC project.

More generally you can try **Anomaly Detection** using algorithms like *Isolation Forest* or *LocalOutlierFactor*. What is critical is to use good features as input. A good starting point would be to calculate *mel-spectrogram* or *MFCC*. The spectrogram frames should be normalized, typically by subtracting the median/mean and dividing by RMS energy.
Run the anomaly detection on individual frames of 20-50ms and then do some filtering of classifications to reduce false triggering. A simple method is to require N consecutive frames to be classified as an anomaly to consider it a real anomaly. Or to require at least P percent of frames within a larger rolling window (say 200-1000ms).

In Python, you can use librosa for [audio feature extraction](https://librosa.github.io/librosa/feature.html) and scikit-learn for [anomaly detection](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/plot_anomaly_comparison.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-plot-anomaly-comparison-py)

Note that for evaluating your method you will need to collect and label a test-set.

Answer (score 0):

If you *just* need a tool to achieve it, you could use Google's SpeechRecognition package. [Here](https://pythonspot.com/speech-recognition-using-google-speech-api/) is a tutorial on how to use it.

It's great because it is able to turn on only when it hears some speech and it's amazing even in noisy environments.

Comment: I am more interested in a general method that is capable of backgound/sound separation, without using pre-learned database. The sound does not necessarily be speech, but, say, animal or machinery sounds, everything that is distinct enough from the background